# Dynamically ignore attributes when saving items with .NET AWS SDK Object Persistence Model

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Is it possible to dynamically ignore some properties when saving items with the .NET Object Persistence Model?

I don't want to decorate my class properties with *DynamoDBIgnore* because sometimes I do want to save the changes being made in those.

I have tried to set *IgnoreNullValues* to true however this did not work when saving items with a batch.

Code is as follows:

```
using (var context = new DynamoDBContext(awsClient, _dynamoDbContextConfig))
{
    var batch = context.CreateBatchWrite<T>(
        new DynamoDBOperationConfig {SkipVersionCheck = true, IgnoreNullValues = true});

    batch.AddPutItems(items);

    await context.ExecuteBatchWriteAsync(new BatchWrite[] {batch});
}
```

Shall I use the lower-level API for achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

The lower level API (exposed through IAmazonDynamoDB / AmazonDynamoDbClient) is the only way I have found till now of updating individual properties of an existing DynamoDB document.

An example of this would be :

```
var updateItemRequest = new UpdateItemRequest
{
    TableName = "search_log_table",
    Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
    {
        {"PK", new AttributeValue("pk_value")},
        {"SK", new AttributeValue("sk_value")}
    },
    UpdateExpression = $"SET SearchCount = if_not_exists(SearchCount, :start) + :inc",
    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
    {
        {":start", new AttributeValue {N = "0"}},
        {":inc", new AttributeValue {N = "1"}}
    },
    ReturnValues = "UPDATED_NEW"
};

// _client is an instance of IAmazonDynamoDB 
return _client.UpdateItemAsync(updateItemRequest);
```

This inserts a new record with `PK = "pk_value", SK = "sk_value"` if one does not exist. 
The statement `UpdateExpression = $"SET SearchCount = if_not_exists(SearchCount, :start) + :inc` sets the `SearchCount` to 1 the first time, and increments the property by 1 on every subsequent invocation